# Sitecore field.GetItems() returns no items on Non English version

Tags: sitecore-api

We have an item which is having a multilist field in it. This field has selected value and the below code is working fine on English version. Other language versions are returning empty result. We have verified the item and dependent list items have the version of other languages. Please help us to fix this issue.

Code

```
public static List<Item> GetMultiListItems(Item dataItem, string fieldName)
{
    if (dataItem != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldName))
    {
        MultilistField field = dataItem.Fields[fieldName];
        if (null == field)
            return null;

        return field.GetItems().ToList();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Is the `dataItem` language equal to `Sitecore.Context.Language`? If not, try to use `using new LanguageSwitcher(item.Language)` around `field.GetItems()`

Comment: Also it is worth to check if you have these items published in the web database for both languages. Check if is there any workflow blocking your publishing for the version of these languages.

Comment: Thank you guys, we have fixed it by applying LanguageSwitcher where we get the dataItem object.

Comment: Comment converted into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `dataItem` language is not equal to `Sitecore.Context.Language`.

Try to use

```
using new LanguageSwitcher(item.Language)
```

around the place where you get your `dataItem` or where you use `field.GetItems()`